# How do I create email alerts for instance stop, start, termination in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I create email alerts for instance stop, start, termination 
in **AWS**?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for posting your question... However there is not enough detail for us to properly answer you! Could you please add more detail, and if you can answer things such as what you want the outcome to be, what you have tried, and what you think may work!

Comment: Hi Trevor,
I would like to receive email alerts for when the instance get started or stopped ,termination

Comment: ahh ok... I get it I misunderstood what you meant!

Comment: There is decent documentation on this topic, refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Amazon CloudWatch alarm actions, you can create alarms that automatically stop, terminate, reboot, or recover your Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances.

For more details read [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html)